# Higher-order function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I got this code when learning about "higher-order function" in JS. I can not figure out how the parameter "m" in this code would be run from 0-5? I understand how the function action(i) is called n times, but which part of this code give the action(i) value from 0 to (n-1)? Thank you.

```
function repeat(n, action) {  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    action(i);  
  }  
}  

function test(condition, result) {  
  if (condition) result();  
}  

repeat(6, m => test(m % 2 == 0, () => {  
    console.log(m);  
    } 
)  
)
```

Comment: You're calling `action(i)` for each number below 6 (`n = 6` -> `i < n; i++`). It's what a [`for` loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) does.

Comment: On the 2nd line: You are looping i from 0~n-1, and gives it as parameter.
So 0~n-1

Comment: Hi Philip. Thank you for your response. Your quote "gives it as parameter" makes me all clear. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is just confusing for the sake of being confusing, but let me have a try...

repeat gets passed 6 and a function that will accept a number as the argument.  The function passed into repeat is test.
Test gets passed in a condition and a function (result).
Repeat runs 6 times and calls test each time, passing the i in repeat to the m in test.
Each time test is run, it checks if m is even, and if so, runs the result function, which is passed in as a callback and just console.logs the value of m.

No matter what number is passed into repeat, m starts at 0 (from i in the for loop). This will print every even number up to, but not including the number passed in.

Comment: Thank you for your time and support. I appreciate you guys helps even it was a dummy question. Now I got the ideal solidly.